# Preserving order in YAML file in Go

Tags: go, yaml

I am trying to read data in a YAML file which looks like this:

```
Category Name:
  Task 1:
    Name: Meeting
    PM: 1
    TC: 0
    STC: 1
    Optional: false
```

There can be multiple tasks in a category and multiple categories. I've originally been reading the YAML file like so.

```
type Task struct {
    Name     string
    PM       string
    TC       string
    STC      string
    Optional bool
}
```

```
type Category struct {
    Name  string
    Tasks []Task
}
```

```
func parseFile() map[string]map[string]map[string]string {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := make(map[string]map[string]map[string]string)
    err1 := yaml.Unmarshal(file, &data)

    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err1)
    }

    return data
}
```

Then I just have a function to loop through the map created in parseFile() and create a list of Category with the filled in information. This works great... other than the fact that the order of categories/tasks written in the YAML file is not preserved because of maps not being ordered.

From reading online, I found that you can preserve the order using yaml.MapSlice{} from gokpg.in/yaml.v2. However, I have no idea what to do with this resulting MapSlice. I can iterate through it to get the categories but I can't iterate through the .Value since MapItems are interfaces, but MapItems would store my list of tasks. What can I do so I can do so I can get the tasks and put in a []Task?

Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Maps are not ordered in Go. So you have to use either another data structure in parallel with a map which would maintain ordering of the map keys or use a custom data structure which would have some properties of a map while also preserving order. That's what `yaml.MapSlice` does. And no, `MapSlice` is not an interface. It's a slice of `MapItem`s which are structs of two fields—a key and its associated value,—and they are indeed of type `interface{}` as they have to be able to represent keys and value of any type. Still, this does not mean you can't iterate over this data structure.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant MapItem for the interface thanks for the correction. For iterating over a MapSlice, that's fine I can use a for-each loop. However the associated value would be the list of tasks and since MapItem is an interface{}, I can't loop through that. Sorry if I've been unclear.

Comment: Also: what prevents you from unmarshaling directly into a `Category` (or `[]Category` if there are multiple of them)? What for would you need a map of maps?

Comment: I also think you should just be using an array/slice. See https://goplay.tools/snippet/NGflxyfL3HQ. A map is inherently unordered.

Comment: @kostix Nothing actually, I started with the map of maps because that's what I saw on tutorials for yaml files similar to my format so I started off with that. To be honest, I didn't even know you could unmarshal directly into my structs.

Comment: @StevenMasley Isn't the example you provided only working if the yaml files contains 1 category? Won't adding more categories cause errors because you're using "Name:" multiple times?

Comment: @BlueCanary, actually, that's what makes this package to work with YAML the most useful ;-) As to your question—why don't you check yourself?

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your directions, I managed to get it to work with order kept and (as a bonus) shorten my full code by 100 lines! haha

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and then accept it—it's a normal practice on SO.

Comment: Yes, I should have supported multiple categories. Seems you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the format of my YAML and structures, then unmarshalling directly into the structure.

The new structs.

```
type Categories struct {
    Category []struct {
        Name string `yaml:"CategoryName"`
        Task []struct {
            Name     string  `yaml:"TaskName"`
            PM       float64 `yaml:"PM"`
            TC       float64 `yaml:"TC"`
            STC      float64 `yaml:"STC"`
            Optional bool    `yaml:"Optional"`
        } `yaml:"Tasks"`
    } `yaml:"Categories"`
}
```

The new format for the YAML file to support what's in the struct.

```
Categories:
  - CategoryName: Category 1
    Tasks:
      - TaskName: Test 1
        PM: 1
        TC: 0
        STC: 1
        Optional: false
      - TaskName: Test 2
        PM: 2
        TC: 0
        STC: 2
        Optional: false
  - CategoryName: Category 2
    Tasks:
      - TaskName: Test 3
        PM: 1
        TC: 2
        STC: 3
        Optional: true
```

Unmarshalling the YAML file directly into a new struct

```
var tasks Categories
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yaml")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    yaml.Unmarshal(file, &tasks)
```

This worked to fix my problem - no longer using maps so the order is preserved and using the structs in a way that I find easy to loop through.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type Config struct {
    CategoryName []map[string]Task `yaml:"CategoryName"`
}

type Task struct {
    Name string `yaml:"Name"`
    PM int `yaml:"PM"`
    TC int `yaml:"TC"`
    STC int `yaml:"STC"`
    Optional bool  `yaml:"Optional"`
}

func main() {
    yamlData := []byte(`
CategoryName:
  - Task1:
      Name: "Meeting"
      PM: 1
      TC: 0
      STC: 1
      Optional: false
  - Task2:
      Name: "Meeting v2"
      PM: 2
      TC: 0
      STC: 2
      Optional: false
`)

    var config Config
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlData, &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Erreur lors de la décomposition du YAML : %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Configuration : %+v\n", config)
}
```